# Creating table to store conditions and using them to filter actual data

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, reporting

I am working on a report that has a separate calculation for each cell and it is huge. Currently using the SAP Crystal report to define the calculation for each cell.

I am looking for solutions to optimize the report. I created an excel to document the calculations. It basically has two tables one has the filter condition(Table 1) and another has actual data(Table 2). I ultimately want to pull $ Amount for Each Account based on the conditions listed in **Table 1**.

Looking forward to suggestions or a different approach that can help achieve the goal.

**Table 1-Conditions**
Account 1        Account 2
Fund              10                 20
Department        41,53                75,62
Location          00                   03
Object            4000,5000,6000       < = 45000
AND <>9000

**Table 2 - Actual Data**

Fund    Department  Location    Object  $Amount
10      41          00          6000    45.00
10      52          00          5000    80.00
20      75          03          41000   45.00
10      53          00          4000    10.00

**Report Result **
Amount
Account 1   $55
Account 2   $45

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDO3O.png)

Answer (score 0):

One of the Crystal Reports management tools listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#doc) allows you to generate Crystal formulas in Excel and import them into your report(s).